# LUIS pre-built entity datetimeV2 does not resolve properly?

Tags: azure-language-understanding

Recently (I'd say since around 2 weeks ago) LUIS has been getting some of the dates wrong for us. And indeed: datetimeV2's start date seems off by a month. Is it a bug or am I misunderstanding this value?

Ex: "since august" returns a start date of 2017-09-01 instead of 2017-08-01.

`{
      "entity": "since august",
      "type": "builtin.datetimeV2.daterange",
      "startIndex": 15,
      "endIndex": 26,
      "resolution": {
        "values": [
          {
            "timex": "XXXX-08",
            "type": "daterange",
            "start": "2017-09-01"
          },
          {
            "timex": "XXXX-08",
            "type": "daterange",
            "start": "2018-09-01"
          }
        ]
      }
    }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can confirm this is an issue. `Since` is currently being handled with the same regex that is being used to handle `after` so the reason of the issue.

In the next days, we will create PR with a proposed fix and I will update this answer with the link to it. We will separate the regexes.

#### Update

A fix for this issue was created and [this is the PR](https://github.com/Microsoft/Recognizers-Text/pull/103) for it.